# relation definition not for primary index columns

Tags: yii, relationship

Database structure is

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->createTable('ar_table_column', array(
    'col_int1' => 'integer NULL',
    'col_int2' => 'integer NULL',
    'col_int3' => 'integer NULL',
    'col_id' => 'pk',
));
Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->createTable('ar_table', array(
    'table_int1' => 'integer NULL',
    'table_int2' => 'integer NULL',
    'table_int3' => 'integer NULL',
    'table_id' => 'pk',
));
Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->createIndex('ar_table_idx', 'ar_table', 
    'table_int1', true);
```

I need such a relation - table can have many columns bound with `ar_table_column.col_int2 = ar_table.table_int1` (not primary key, but note that `table_int1` is unique). I need this relation from column point of view, i.e. I need to have access to table from each column.

First trial:

```
'table' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'ArTable', '', 
    'on' => 't.col_int2=table.table_int1', ),
```

And this is a half-good solution. There are 2 cases. First:

```
$columnInRelation = ArColumn::model()->with('table')->find();
$tableInRelation = $columnInRelation->table;
var_export($tableInRelation->attributes);
```

and it works well - I get correct array of attributes.

Second case:

```
$columnInRelation = ArColumn::model()->find();
$tableInRelation = $columnInRelation->table;
var_export($tableInRelation->attributes);
```

and there I get a SQL error from query:

SELECT table.table_int1 AS t1_c0, table.table_int2 AS t1_c1, table.table_int3 AS t1_c2, table.table_id AS t1_c3 FROM ar_table table WHERE (t.col_int2=table.table_int1)

Error is obvious.

How should I define relation to have it available in both cases - using `with()` and not using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relation should be according to http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr

```
'table' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'ArTable', array('col_int2' => 'table_int1')),
```